# C# .Net Framework 3.5 - System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, .net

I've a following issue and tried multiple variations to try to solve this issue:

```
bool selectOnlyPublished = Convert.ToBoolean((CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite).ToString().ToLower());
TreeNode blogNode = BlogHelper.GetParentBlog(aliasPath, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, selectOnlyPublished);
```

but it still throws :System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean. error.

i've tried the followings:

- Boolean.Parse()
- Boolean.Parse(string.ToLower())
- Even hardcoded a value of the type boolean.

But they all gave me the same error.

Comment: Why not just `bool selectOnlyPublished = CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite;`? Why would you want to convert it into a string and then convert it back into a boolean, when you already have a boolean in the first place?

Comment: Post the call stack so we know which line to care about.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just do this:

```
bool selectOnlyPublished = CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite;
TreeNode blogNode = BlogHelper.GetParentBlog(
    aliasPath, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, selectOnlyPublished);
```

Comment: That was the initial statement but it failed. Sorry i omitted to mention it.

Comment: Failed *how* exactly? (exception message?)

Comment: It gave the following error : System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Comment: There is no string in `bool selectOnlyPublished = CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite;`.

Comment: So either (a) it is not failing on the `bool ...` line, (b) `.ViewMode` does some string formatting, or (c) .`LiveSite` does some string formatting.

Comment: My guess is that the result of == on these operands is not actually a Boolean.

Comment: Assuming that `ViewModeEnum` is actually an enum, and there no overloaded `==` operator, implicit cast operators, or anything else strange, there is no way this code should produce a `FormatException`.

Comment: The .ViewMode return an object of the type ViewModeEnum and value as the .LiveSite .

Comment: I wonder how to get [==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53k8ybth.aspx) to *not* return a boolean. So yeah, like @AustinSalonen said, either `.ViewMode` or `.LiveSite` do some string formatting, or it isn't possible that this line will throw that error.

Comment: @Corak:  example:  `public static int operator ==(X left, X right) { return 12; }` is valid code.  It will confuse the hell out of whoever is using it but it is valid.

Comment: That the strange thing i expected that line to throw the error  but it passes successfully and rather throw the error in the method below.

Comment: So the error isn't from any code you've posted here? Or is it from the second line you posted? Either way, your original problem is solved.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - O_o wow. That is *evil*... thanks for showing that, but can we please all forget now that this is even possible? ^_^;

Comment: @MikePrecup The error is from the line of 2 line of code where the boolean has been created and the problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: @Raymond The the problem is somewhere *inside* of the method `BlogHelper.GetParentBlog`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I thought so and cross-checked, that method BlogHelper.GetParentBlog  is working  with the same params in a different project. Both projects use the same CMS_Blog.dll (It's Kentico CMS)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you converting the result of `CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite` to a bool? The result of that code will be a bool type already. You can just do:

```
bool selectOnlyPublished = CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite;
```

To answer your original question, the result of [`Convert.ToBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx) is

> true if value equals TrueString, or false if value equals FalseString or null.

The value of `TrueString` is `True` and `FalseString` is `False`. Take off your `ToLower` on your string and it should parse correctly.

Comment: Just tried our options yielded the same results (FormatException)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try

```
TreeNode blogNode = BlogHelper.GetParentBlog(
    aliasPath, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, 
    (CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite)
);
```

I assume that the data type of *CMSContext.ViewMode* is *ViewModeEnum*?

Comment: Same result FormatException

Comment: Ok, what happens if you just use
    bool SelectOnlyPublished = (CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite);
    TreeNode blogNode;

and don't use the constructor? Are you still getting the FormatException error? Because I'm beginning to think the FormatException is to the TreeNode constructor and not the boolean; unless ViewMode is type string and ViewModeEnum is an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you parsing the boolean in the first place

```
bool selectOnlyPublished = (CMSContext.ViewMode == ViewModeEnum.LiveSite);
```

should do the job